# Is a finite subset of a partially ordered set bounded?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Suppose $X$ is a partially ordered set. Let $A$ be a finite subset of $X$. Is $A$ bounded? (That is, do there exist upper and lower bounds for $A$?)

It seems false but unable to find a counter example.

Comment: Defined bounded.  What happens if $X$ is discrete - that is $x\leq y$ if and only if $x=y$?

Comment: If by bounded you mean that there is $M$ such that all elements of $A$ are smaller than $M$, then it's obviously false, as your partial order could be just equality for instance.

Comment: By bounded i meant there is a upper and a lower bound not just a M such that all elements are less than or equal to it

Answer (score 2):

Every finite partial order has a maximal (and minimal) element, and the subset of maximal/minimal elements make a boundary to $A$.

If you are talking about an element strictly larger than all the points in $A$ then the answer would be negative, for example $A=X=\{0,1\}$ in the discrete order.

Comment: What if $X$ has at most $1$ element?

Comment: It is common to consider partial orders as non-empty sets. Much like most first-order structures. If there is one element, then it is its own upper bound.

Comment: If there is only one element A would be clearly bounded